# Cannot retrieve log groups in CloudWatch with AWS CloudWatch EC2 linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have been trying to retrieve a log file i created in a directory to Cloud Watch: /home/sampleFolder/sampleLogs.log

Despite different methods on installing cloud watch agent, the log groups tab didn't show up the log group from the EC2. What I did was:

1. Create new IAM Role

- Select CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy

2. Attach the role to my EC2 Linux
3. Install CloudWatchAgent on my EC2

- sudo yum install amazon-cloudwatch-agent

4. Create config.json file

- Location: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json
- Content:

```
{
    "agent": {
        "run_as_user": "root"
    },
    "logs": {
        "logs_collected": {
            "files": {
                "collect_list": [
                    {
                        "file_path": "/home/sampleFolder/sampleLogs.log",
                        "log_group_name": "SampleLogs",
                        "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

5. Start the agent

- sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json -s

6. Reboot EC2

I also checked the cloudwatch agent logs and I can see:
"pumping data from /home/sampleFolder/sampleLogs.log to cloudwatchlogs"

Note that, I've tried different methods of installing CloudWatch Agent:

1. Via system manager: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAnIhIwE5hY
2. Via cmd lines:

- Old cloudwatch agent: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-commandline-fleet.html
- Updated cloudwatch agent: https://www.rapidspike.com/blog/how-to-send-log-files-to-aws-cloudwatch-ubuntu/

Any ideas would help!

Comment: The procedure is correct. Are you sure that `/home/sampleFolder/sampleLogs.log` is correct path and it has any content?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it has a JSON message within it